# HoloLens 2 / Unity : Start Menu Icon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, icons, hololens, startmenu

Unity Version: 2020.3.29f1

I want to assign an Icon for my app on the HoloLens 2 start menu

I've created assigned all the icons under:

```
Unity > Project Settings > Player
```

However my icon is still the default.

I tried uninstalling my app manually from the HoloLens 2 and rebuilding the project.

[image: HoloLens 2 Start Menu]

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After writing this question out I found the cause for me at least.

I had to delete the whole build folder and recreate it, then my Icon appeared on the HoloLens start menu.

I would guess there are some files which arn't recreated each time you do a build.